# angular 2 active route is on single route

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

say that I have the following html that specifies links for different parts.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{'Analytics':700}" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:false}">Home</a>
      <input type="text" #id (input)="0"/>
      <a [routerLink]="['user',id.value]" [queryParams]="{'Analytics':500}" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:false}">User</a>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onNavigate()">click me</button>

      <hr>
```

what I expect is that for a given path like **/user/15/edit** my both links became red (are affected by active class)however they work for just **exact** paths that is just when I click on the very link ,that would be **activated**.

[image]

[image]

the above url is that the User link refers to.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want both of your links to have 'active' even though you only click one of them?

Comment: yes !by default It must be the case that active link must be decided on the base of starting url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) in this case to add an active class based on some routing logic. This is in some shape or form what routerLinkActive does. So you can do something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{'Analytics':700}" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isMyRoute }">Home</a>
```

And in your component use [Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html) and [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#url-anchor) to check for the component name by traversing the route tree that is displayed in router outlet and toggle a variable based on that:

```
import {ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
... 
public isMyRoute: boolean;

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(res => {
      if (res instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let fn = this.route.children[0].component;
        let componentName = fn['name'];

        if (componentName === 'UserEditComponent') {
          this.isMyRoute = true;
        } else {
          this.isMyRoute = false;
        }
      }
    })
}
```